# SAS: No valid observations are found Error - Simple Regression

Tags: sas, regression

I have big panel time series data set. I wish to do this basic SAS regression code:

```
proc sort data=dataset;
by time_id;
run;

ods output parameterestimates=pe;
proc reg data=dataset;
by time_id;
model y=x1 x2 x3....x15;
quit;
run;
```

I get this error when I run the code:

```
ERROR: No valid observations are found.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      time_id=1
ERROR: No valid observations are found.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      time_id=2....
```

Why? My time_id variable exists... is it because I have too many time_id variables? If I select firm_id it works but I want time_id.

Here's a sample of my data (panel time series):

```
y     x  firm_id time_id
3.4   100   1   1
2.3   200   1   2
6.5   653   1   3
3     50    2   1
4.34  23    2   2
4.8   55    2   3
1.311 400   3   1
1.23  200   3   2
5.63  50    3   3
```

Comment: Providing sample data would be helpful in identifying the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this error message if all values of a particular x variable are missing for a given time_id.  Take a look at the example below where all values of x2 are missing for time_id 1, when you run the code the Results Output window details the problem (number of missing observations the same as the number of observations).
It works for firm_id because you have fewer values than time_id, therefore not all values of a particular x variable are missing for each firm_id.

```
data have;
input y x1 x2 firm_id time_id;
cards;
3.4   100   .   1   1
2.3   200   200 1   2
6.5   653   653 1   3
3     50    .   2   1
4.34  23    23  2   2
4.8   55    55  2   3
1.311 400   .   3   1
1.23  200   200 3   2
5.63  50    50  3   3
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by time_id;
run;

ods output parameterestimates=pe;
proc reg data=have;
by time_id;
model y=x1-x2;
quit;
run;
```